# DJI FPV Air Unit mistakenly declares "slow card"

Tags: first-person-view, troubleshooting, osd, dji-air-unit

Getting a slow sd card in my DJI goggles screen indicating the message for the air unit.

Using a 64gb SanDisk Extreme Pro Card.

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the SD card with something else?

Comment: Looks like this is a *very* common issue for people to have with no clear solution, as documented on the DJI product forums: https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=212878&pid=2130145

Comment: Appreciate the help ifconfig. looks like  there is a bug in the latest update. :-)

Comment: No problem, man! Just hope DJI gets around to fixing this soon. Looks like the FPV system is mostly inoperative without this working well...

Comment: During reading your question I was like: "Get yourself a SanDisk Extreme Pro. Their 60MB/s continuous write speed is super awesome. If you get a deal on them, they can also be fairly inexpensive". And then you mentioned you already have one of those lol

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this issue where perfectly good and speedy SD cards are declared "slow" in DJI Air Units, as is documented on the [DJI product forums](https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=212878&pid=2130145). This is an issue for many DJI FPV system users.